# Method isupper Unicode-friendly in Python 2?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I'm using this line in my code for counting uppercase letters in a string:

```
text = "Áno"
count = sum(1 for c in text if c.isupper())
```

This code returns 0, but I expect 1 (as 'Á' is uppercase)
How can I count uppercase letters with Unicode characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For python 2 you need to add a `u`, your string is not actually unicode:

```
text = u"Áno"
```

You can also write your expression as `count = sum(c.isupper() for c in text)`, `c.isupper()` will return True or False so 1 or 0.

```
In [1]: text = "Áno"

In [2]: count = sum(c.isupper() for c in text)

In [3]: count
Out[3]: 0    
In [4]: text = u"Áno"
In [5]: count = sum(c.isupper() for c in text)    
In [6]: count
Out[6]: 1
In [7]: text = "Áno".decode("utf-8")   
In [8]: count = sum(c.isupper() for c in text)    
In [9]: count
Out[9]: 1
```

Comment: (1) If it is Python 2 then there should be also an encoding declaration at the top (to allow non-ascii string literals). (2) You could also add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to make Unicode to be the default for `''` string literals.  (3) `any(c.isupper() for c in text)` if you only interested in True/False.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, the `str.isupper()` method only works on *ASCII characters*. You almost certainly have a Python 2 bytestring and it'll depend on the encoding what exact bytes you have there, but they are not going to be valid ASCII bytes.

Decode the string to a Unicode value or use a Unicode literal (`u'Áno'`), so that `unicode.isupper()` can determine uppercase characters according to the Unicode standard:

```
>>> u'Áno'[0].isupper()
True
```

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Answer (score 0):

for english word there is a module for all capital alphabet. if you put all your capital alphabet in a variable, the code below works too:

```
import string
a=string.ascii_uppercase
s='ThiS is A tEst'
count=0
for i in s:
    if i in a:
        count+=1

print(count)
```